# micrometer - spring boot 3 - rest template - traceids are not propagated as expected

Tags: micrometer, distributed-tracing, spring-resttemplate, spring-boot-3, micrometer-tracing

I have two spring boot services A and B.

Service A uses a RestTemplate to call an endpoint in Service B.

RestTemplate and the call in Service A looks like below:

```
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate simpleRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }



restTemplate.exchange(
          endpoint,
          HttpMethod.GET,
          HttpEntity.EMPTY,
          new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
          }
      );
```

Now, I notice that the traceId logged in Service A is different from the one logged in Service B. How do I make the traceId Service A to propagate to Service B when an endpoint is called using the RestTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding a solution that worked for me. Hope it helps someone.

I added gradle dependency below:

```
[group: 'io.zipkin.brave', name: 'brave-instrumentation-spring-web']
```

I built RestTemplate as below:

```
 @Bean
  public HttpTracing create(final Tracing tracing) {
    return HttpTracing
        .newBuilder(tracing)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate simpleRestTemplate(final HttpTracing httpTracing) {
    return  new RestTemplateBuilder()
        .interceptors(TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.create(httpTracing))
        .build();
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are explicitly telling Spring Framework that you want to use a `RestTemplate` that you don't want to be instrumented.

Please read the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/observability.html#observability.http-client.resttemplate), you need to create a `RestTemplate` bean from the builder that Spring provides:

```java
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: This is correct. I also had to add libraries related to instrumentation manually in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is incorrect, check the docs I linked. ;) Also, RestTemplate is instrumented by the Spring team using Micrometer, if you want to use that instrumentation (what the docs refers to), you need to add Micrometer dependencies (again, see the docs).